# IE7 crashed when RemoveDialogHandler is called

Tags: internet-explorer-7, watin

I have this code:

```
FileDownloadHandler handler = new FileDownloadHandler(fileName);
Browser.AddDialogHandler(handler);
//using (new UseDialogOnce(Browser.DialogWatcher, handler))
//{
    Browser.Button(Find.ById("ButtonExportReport")).ClickNoWait();
    handler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(20);
    handler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(30);
    Console.WriteLine("download finish: " + handler.HasHandledFileDownloadDialog);
//}
Browser.RemoveDialogHandler(handler);
```

And when I call `Browser.RemoveDialogHandler`, Internet Explorer 7 crashes with the message:

> "no installed debugger has
>   just_in-time debugging enabled"

(I don't know how to debug IE7 because I only have the CLR debugger which can debug only managed code)

Do you know what I should do ? Any path where I should look for information ?

Thanks

### EDIT1:

In fact the error is not caused by the `.RemoveDialogHandler`
I added

```
ZvLogManager.Info("start wait");
Thread.Sleep(10000); // wait 10 seconds
ZvLogManager.Info("end wait");
```

just before the `.RemoveDialogHandler`, and I get the error message of IE between the "start wait" and "end wait".

So it is file download that makes it crash after 5 seconds. Any idea ?

### EDIT 2:

I enable the logging in WatiN and I get:

> [Action]: Clicking (no wait) Button 'ButtonExportReport',
>
> [Action]: Clicking on '&Save'
>
> [Action]: Clicking on '&Save'
>
> [Action]: Download started at 4:21:13 PM
>
> [Action]: Clicked Save
>
> [Action]: Saving Download file as c:\temp\export_file634296648679859966.xls
>
> [Action]: Clicking on '&Save'
>
> [Action]: Clicking on 'Close'
>
> [Action]: Download complete at 4:21:17 PM
>
> INFO download finish: True
>
> INFO start wait
>
> INFO end wait

This is not very helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally install VS on the server where IE7 was crashing in order to debug IE (!!!). I get an exception: "`Unhandled exception in iexplore.exe  Access violation reading location`"

After googling it, I found this [website](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/247295-IE7-Problem-iexploreexe-crashes) and it proposes me to reset all settings: `Options -> Advanced -> Reset Internet Explorer Settings`.

And I have no more crash !